# Infinite Loop when getting to end of file

Tags: php, php-5.6

I'm trying to get a PHP function to read information from a text file and return it as an array. My function seems to work well at the beginning of the file, but get's stuck at the end of the file, or when this file is empty.

Here is my function and the text file :

```
function readBook($file) {
    $book = [];
    $line = trim(fgets($file));
    // Get rid of white lines at start of file
    while ($line !== false && strlen($line) === 0) {
      $line = trim(fgets($file));
    }
    if ($line === false) {
      return false;
    }
    // Prepare and return the array
    while ($line !== false && strlen($line) > 0) {
      $pos = strpos($line, ":");
      if ($pos != false) {
        $key = trim(substr($line, 0, $pos));
        $value = trim(substr($line, $pos + 1));
        $book[$key] = $value;
        //echo $line . "\n";
        $line = trim(fgets($file));
      } else {
        throw new \Exception("Erreur - Fichier mal écrit", 125);
      }
    }

    return $book;
  }
```

The text file is :

```
couverture : scorpion.jpg
titre : La marque du diable
serie : Le Scorpion
auteurs : Marini - Desberg
année : 2000
catégorie : bandes-dessinées

couverture : BOB.jpg
titre : La marque du BOB
serie : Le BOB
auteurs : Marini - Desberg
année : 2000
catégorie : bandes-dessinées
```

When calling the function 3 times on this example, it should return the two books only. What it does now is return the two books and get stuck in an infinite loading loop.

Could you guys help me out here ?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At EOF, `trim(fgets($fileHandle))` returns `""` instead of `false`

Change at start

```
$line = trim(fgets($file));
while ($line !== false && strlen($line) === 0) {
```

by

```
$line = fgets($file);
while ($line !== false && strlen(trim($line)) === 0) {
   $line = fgets($file);
}
```